# Spring Boot turn off logging for a package

Tags: logging, spring-boot, properties

I prefer to throw my own exceptions for business logic. For example I have a class com.mine.exception.DuplicateClientException. Is there some configuration where I can turn off printing the stack trace for package com.mine.exception ?

Something like:

```
logging.level.com.mine.exception=OFF
```

Answer (score 6):

In application.properties you can add ‘logging.level.*=LEVEL’ where ‘LEVEL’ is one of TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, OFF. * is responsible for package/class.

For example

```
logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

This means that root logger has WARN level. org.springframework.web is on DEBUG level, but all hibernates files are logged only ERROR.